# Efficiently repeat a character/string n times in Scala

Tags: string, scala, char, concatenation, string-concatenation

I would like to do the following more efficiently:

```
def repeatChar(char:Char, n: Int) = List.fill(n)(char).mkString
def repeatString(char:String, n: Int) = List.fill(n)(char).mkString

repeatChar('a',3)     // res0: String = aaa
repeatString("abc",3) // res0: String = abcabcabc
```

Comment: It might be slightly more efficient if you use `Stream`instead of `List`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

For strings you can just write `"abc" * 3`, which works via [`StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) and uses a `StringBuffer` behind the scenes.

For characters I think your solution is pretty reasonable, although `char.toString * n` is arguably clearer. Do you have any reason to suspect the `List.fill` version isn't efficient enough for your needs? You could write your own method that would use a `StringBuffer` (similar to `*` on `StringOps`), but I would suggest aiming for clarity first and then worrying about efficiency only when you have concrete evidence that that's an issue in your program.

Comment: Thank you Travis. This was more out of academic interest and, as you suggested, to improve clarity if possible, rather than a need to improve performance. I just wanted to make sure I'm picking up the best practices from the beginning.

Comment: @TimY That makes sense—I wish more people would use "efficiency" in contexts other than performance!

Comment: Not sure how being reasonable has been determined here: does this answer rely on any benchmark against other options, such as manipulating plain Java strings or anything else, or did you rather mean this is the idiomatic way in scala?

Comment: @TravisBrown What if n is Long? What this solution will work?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Why not try it?

Comment: You can always call `toInt` on a `Long` (which will overflow if the `Long` is too large, but that seems unlikely to be a meaningful case here, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply define:

```
def repeatChar(char:Char, n: Int) = char.toString() * n
def repeatString(char:String, n: Int) = char * n
```

Comment: .repeat(n) is not a method in String.

Comment: My Bad. I had java.lang package also included as i was writing gatling simulation in Scala to test java application. I didn't realise that i am using java.lang.String for repeat method.

Comment: How is this different, in any meaningful way, from the accepted answer of 6 years ago?

Comment: That's better. Upped the vote.