# Parameterized white space?

Tags: scala

What is the easiest way to generate `ind` many space? Any easier way other than using `foldRight`?

```
   (1 to ind).foldRight("") {
      case (_, a) => a + " "
   }
```

Comment: What are you going to do next? Assuming this is for padding some more meaningful output, then `StringOps.format` or `f""` string interpolation along with your other output is probably more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
' '.toString * ind
```

Have a look at this, explaining the more generic case in detail: [Efficiently repeat a character/string n times in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637100/efficiently-repeat-a-character-string-n-times-in-scala)