# Symbolic Function not invoked

Tags: scala, function

I am new to Scala. I was trying to create functions like `+`, `*` in one of the class.
Below is the class and its definition -

```scala
case class StringWrapper2(str : String){
  def +(x:Int) : String ={
    println(s"x: $x, str :$str")
    str.concat(x.toString);
  }
  def *(x:Int) : String = {
    println(s"x: $x, str :$str")
    str.repeat(x);
  }
}
```

I created instance and called above function -

```scala
val sw: StringWrapper2 = new StringWrapper2("ABC")
val result = sw + 10 * 2
```

I am expecting the result - ABC10ABC10
But I am getting result as ABC20

Also the `println` statements that I added in method are not printed.
It means these symbolic methods are not getting called and some different implementation (probably String class) is getting called.

Any idea why this might be happening and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's because of the order of the operators. Try to do `(sw + 10)* 2`. But Just for you know `String` has + and `StringOps` has `*` See [Efficiently repeat a character/string n times in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637882/2359227)

Comment: Rahul, will you accept my answer?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922456/2359227), `*` is calculated before `+`. For example `2 + 2 * 2` [will result in 6, and not 8](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/a6PYlvX2QVyhpDoOl9H5xA).

In your example, `10 * 2` is calculated before, resulting in `20`, and then when you add `sw + 20` you get `ABC20`.

To your second question. Please note that in your example the `println` from the `+` method [is printed](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/IlDIv5V8RSOPcdZ8feOvmQ/1). The reason the second line isn't printed, is that you return a `String`, instead of `StringWrapper`. To get what you want, you need to do something like:

```scala
case class StringWrapper2(str : String){
  def +(x:Int) : StringWrapper2 ={
    println(s"x: $x, str :$str")
    StringWrapper2(str.concat(x.toString))
  }
  def *(x:Int) : StringWrapper2 = {
    println(s"x: $x, str :$str")
    StringWrapper2(str * x)
  }
}

val sw: StringWrapper2 = new StringWrapper2("ABC")
val result = (sw + 10) * 2
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/IlDIv5V8RSOPcdZ8feOvmQ/2).